# настройка nginx (cms OpenCart - ЧПУ)

Tags: nginx

Здравствуйте суть вопроса настройки сервера

```
rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?_route_=$1 last;
```

о так сейчас сделан rewrite с ЧПУ работает вида site.ru/en/contact и site.ru/contact все работает но когда идет не ЧПУ типа site.ru/en/index.php?route=contact - No input file specified.
а site.ru/index.php?route=contact - все работает

в чем проблема ?
Весь конфиг

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name jetroll.dev;

    root /home/www/jetroll.dev;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/jetroll.dev.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/jetroll.dev.error.log;

    rewrite /admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @opencart;
    }

    location @opencart {
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?_route_=$1 last;
    }


    location /admin {
        index index.php;
    }

    rewrite ^/sitemap.xml$ /index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap last;
    rewrite ^/googlebase.xml$ /index.php?route=feed/google_base last;
    rewrite ^/download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found last;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    sendfile off;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-your_user.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: полный конфиг nginx, э?

Comment: добавил ниже как ответ

Comment: понятно. а ошибка `No input file specified` - это же ошибка бекенда, верно? короче, nginx тут не при чём. запрос `/en/*.php` заходит в локейшн обрабатывающий `\.php` и честно передаётся на бекенд.

Comment: как исправить настройку

тотже код на хостингу под nginx работает
а у себя не могу настроить

Comment: либо научить бекенд обрабатывать такие урлы, либо написать `location ~ ^/en/.+\.php$`, который будет делать что-то дополнительное с такими запросами. первый вариант архитектурно правильней, имхо

Comment: php обрабатывает под апач все гуд, на хостингу чисто для пробы под nginx все работает а на vps не настрою, все урлы с ЧПУ правильно работают а  запросы LANG\index.php?route === No input file specified

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31146/discussion-between-papa777-and-norbornen).

Comment: запрос не попадает на backend

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nginx_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)#.D0.9E.D1.88.D0.B8.D0.B1.D0.BA.D0.B0:_No_input_file_specified

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=No+input+file+specified

Comment: спасибо, но пока только на 50% ЗАРАБОТАЛО
запрос с кодом, но возврат только на языку по дефолту буду смотреть куда оно идет :)

Answer (score 1):

Для истории, или кому тоже надо будет решение следуещее

```
 location ~ \.php$ {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?_route_=$1 last;
    }
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-your_user.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
}
```

вроде помогло :)

Comment: Спасибо, Помогло добавление `if (!-e $request_filename){ rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?_route_=$1 last; }`.